# points.addxy from stored procedure

Tags: c#, graphing

I am trying to return the results to a chart and graph it. My database data returned is a datetime and a float which should work since they are both objects. The error I get is

> cannot convert from `string` to `int`

for both arguments in the `AddXY` method.

```
string dateSelected = monthCalendarAdv1.Value.ToShortDateString();
dataConnection.Open();

SqlCommand dataCommand4 = new SqlCommand("SpTimeSeriesTotalParity", dataConnection);
dataCommand4.Connection = dataConnection;
dataCommand4.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
dataCommand4.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ValDate", dateSelected));
dataCommand4.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Acct", cmbSelectAccno.Text));
```

The following code was similar and was working for the first argument without any issue.

```
this.chart1.Series["$Parity"].Points.AddXY("Item1",1);
this.chart1.Series["$Parity"].Points.AddXY("Item2", 2); 
this.chart1.Series["$Parity"].Points.AddXY("Item3", 3); 
this.chart1.Series["$Parity"].Points.AddXY("Item4", 4); 
this.chart1.Series["$Parity"].Points.AddXY("Item5", 5); 

try
{
    dataConnection.Open();
    using (SqlDataReader myReader = dataCommand4.ExecuteReader())
                    // myReader = dataConnection.ExecuteReader();
       while (myReader.Read())
       {
           this.chart1.Series["$Parity"].Points.AddXY
              (myReader.GetDateTime("ValuationDate"), myReader.GetDouble("SumParity"));
       }
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is not your addxy method, but the Command reader getter methods.

Both expect the 0-Based index of the column and not it's name.

Change your code to something like this:

```
this.chart1.Series ["$Parity"].Points.AddXY (myReader.GetDateTime(2), myReader.GetDouble(3));
```

Comment: The following code was similar and was working for the first argument without any issue. 
this.chart1.Series["$Parity"].Points.AddXY("Item1",1);
              this.chart1.Series["$Parity"].Points.AddXY("Item2", 2);
              this.chart1.Series["$Parity"].Points.AddXY("Item3", 3);
              this.chart1.Series["$Parity"].Points.AddXY("Item4", 4);
              this.chart1.Series["$Parity"].Points.AddXY("Item5", 5);

Comment: additionally :
Syntax
C#
C++
F#
VB

public int AddXY(
 Object xValue,
 params Object[] yValue
)

Parameters

xValue
    Type: System.Object
    The X value of the data point.

yValue
    Type: System.Object[]
    One o